# How to show Python/JavaScript code in the Microsoft MakeCode Arcade Learning platform

Tags: microsoft

How to show the Python/JavaScript code behind the blocks of the Microsoft MakeCode Arcade platform, here with the screenshot of the first level of the beginner's arcade "Full of Stories"?

I do not see the button to change to the code view:

[image]

The full window looks like this:

[image]

You will not help me guessing whether one of the menus, settings or buttons will do it, I have tried them. And it is not a refresh/restart thing.

Tested with: Firefox on Linux Mint 20.04 and Windows 10, Safari on iPad with iPadOS 16.6.

Comment: How do you get to this page? Do you open it from the browser history, a browser favorite, by following a link that someone shared with you? Does this project was created by you or by someone else? Have you tried the basic troubleshooting, like refreshing the page, opening in private / safe / incognito mode / using another web browser? The screenshot isn't complete, it's not showing all the top elements / typical web app toolbar menus / options. Have you looked thoroughly at all the user interface elements?

Comment: @Rubén This screenshot is not for you to search for a missing button somewhere on the screen, it is to show that the dropdown menu for the code is missing. I have changed the screenshot so that this is clearer. Your ideas welcome, but I searched for such a menu or button for quite some time, of course, and it is not a refresh or restart thing. Anyway, the answer is already there, and the code seems to be written only when saving the level as a project (static code).

Comment: Thanks for replying. If the image doesn't include the web app borders, it's unclear whether the menu is missing or out of the screen. The question should be clear independently if the answer is already posted or self-answered. The new screenshot, which includes an annotation about the missing menu, is much better. P.S. I was not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rubén This must be a misunderstanding then. It is just how the projects work: unless you save and open as a project, you do not get the code editor. Show me anything else, and the accepted answer is yours. There is now a full screenshot with some remarks to make the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just understood the misunderstanding. You are trying to see the code on one of the Skillmaps, while I was looking at a project created from scratch. If there are no updates in the question/answer I will add an answer or more comments later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important detail is that the OP scenario uses a project opened from a MakeCode Skillmaps / Tutorial section as the starting point. Projects opened in Skillmap / Tutorial mode show a particular user interface, including a left sidebar showing the tutorial instructions and hiding some user interface elements, like the button to show the code, among other things.

To have access to the code, instead of accessing the project through the Skillmap / Tutorial sections, access the project through My Projects.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the last step of the arcade (you can also jump there without doing anything) and click on "Save in 'my projects'" (works without registration):

[image]

It should open the main site with the projects listed, or you open the main page of Microsoft MakeCode with all of the projects to choose from. Do not forget to refresh the site / F5 if you do not open it in a new tab. If you have already finished a project, it should pop up in the main list of projects:

[image]

Only if you then click on it, taken from the projects, from the main menu, you will have the choice in the upper task bar for Python/JavaScript:

[image]